# Application in permanent wait on Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, slimdx

I have a problem with invoking some graphic methods in the main thread of my application. Im using SlimDX to render in a control of my window. To execute graphics code in the main thread im using the forms `Invoke`. Usually this works without any problems but sometimes (no fixed time interval) the application freezes and the debugger tells me that the application is in a wait state.

The code is the following:

```
public void CallOnThread(Action action)
{
    if (mWindow.InvokeRequired)
        action();
    else
        mWindow.Invoke(action);
}
```

The window (a `System.Windows.Forms.Fom`) is run using SlimDXs `MessagePump.Run`.

Ive seen other postings where `Dispatcher.Run` was suggested but that actually just blocks the whole thread not running any rendering.

What is the reason for that behaviour?

Thanks and greetings

Comment: your `if` and `else` clause seem like they should be reversed

Comment: Kinda embarrassing. After removing my own implementation using System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher and using Form.Invoke i inserted that little thing as a new error... So far it seems to work with the reversed if. Its to late...

Answer (score 0):

In that case the answer is just the inverted if-statement.

```
public void CallOnThread(Action action)
{
    if (!mWindow.InvokeRequired)
        action();
    else
        mWindow.Invoke(action);
}
```